# How to obtain a confidence interval or a measure of prediction dispersion when using xgboost for classification?

Tags: machine-learning, confidence-interval, boosting

How to obtain a confidence interval or a measure of prediction dispersion when using xgboost for classification?

So for example, if xgboost predicts a probability of an event is 0.9, how can the confidence in that probability be obtained?

Also is this confidence assumed to be heteroskedastic?